# Multifield required validation is not working in client side in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I used to implement multi field required validation using this link [MVC3 Validating Multiple Fields As A Single Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013172/mvc3-validating-multiple-fields-as-a-single-property)

But it did not work at my end.

Below is the code I used.

**Javascript**

```
    $.validator.addMethod('multifield', function (value, element, params) {
    var properties = params.propertyname.split(',');
    var isValid = false;
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        var property = properties[i];
        if ($('#' + property).val() != "") {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (properties.length == count) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}, '');

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('multifield', ['propertyname'], function (options) {
    options.rules['multifield'] = options.params;
    options.messages['multifield'] = options.message;
}
);
```

**Class**

```
  public class Customer
    {
       public string AreaCode { get; set; }
      [MultiFieldRequired(new string[2] { "AreaCode", "PhoneNumber" }, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a phone number")]
       public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class MultiFieldRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    string propertyName;
    private readonly string[] _fields;

    public MultiFieldRequiredAttribute(string[] fields)
    {
        _fields = fields;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        foreach (string field in _fields)
        {
            propertyName = field;
            PropertyInfo property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(field);
            if (property == null)
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Property '{0}' is undefined.", field));

            var fieldValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (fieldValue == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldValue.ToString()))
                return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

     public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        // The value we set here are needed by the jQuery adapter
        ModelClientValidationRule multifield = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        multifield.ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage;
        multifield.ValidationType = "multifield"; // This is the name the jQuery validator will use
        //"otherpropertyname" is the name of the jQuery parameter for the adapter, must be LOWERCASE!
        multifield.ValidationParameters.Add("propertyname", string.Join(",", _fields));

        yield return multifield;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
    {


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AreaCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AreaCode)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    </div>
          <button type="submit" tabindex="19" class="form-control btn btn-primary" style="float: right; margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 10px;">Submit</button>
    }
```

Comment: What is not working - client side or server side validation or both? You have implemented `IClientValidatable` but have not shown your scripts to add the rules to the `$.validator` which are necessary for client side validation

Comment: Both server side and client side didn't work. Also I don't know about #.validator changes that I need to do in javascript

Comment: To understand what you need for client side validation, refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2). But its not really clear what your wanting to do. If your wanting to have a Required validation attribute on `PhoneNumber` that also ensure that `AreaCode` has a value then you should one attribute applied to `PhoneNumber` only and that attribute accepts a parameter for the nae of the other property.

Comment: And it should be `return ValidationResult.Success;` (not `return null;`)

Comment: I have added javascript code  as well...could you please find the issue and resolve the same now

Comment: Your scripts have no relationship to the code in your `ValidationAttribute` - all its doing is checking the the the value of the current control is not `null`.  And you not using the value of `propertyName` (and in any case, your never assign a value to `propertyName` so it would be `null` anyway)

Comment: I added ``multifield.ValidationParameters.Add("propertyname", propertyName); `` to add value in property name.. Could you please help in javascript code..I don't know what to write there ...

Comment: But the value of `propertyName` is `null` (you never set it), and you never use it in the script anyway. As I noted before, there is no point doing this - your adding a validation attribute to `AreaCode`,  but then ignoring it. You should have one attribute applied to `PhoneNumber` (say) `[RequiredWith("AreaCode")]` and that attribute is responsible for testing that both `PhoneNumber` and `AreaCode` are not null

Comment: I have removed the attribute and u r right, propertyname is coming as null. but when I try server side it contains values from ``propertyName = field;`` If you can please correct the changes wherever you think is wrong...

Comment: No time now, but I'll add an answer based on my previous comments tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you linked to and the code you have based it on does not make a lot of sense. Applying a validation attribute to your `AreaCode` property without including an associated `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` is pointless.

If you want a validation message associated with `PhoneNumber` that will display a *Please enter a phone number* error if it's empty, and to display a *Please also enter an Area Code* if its not empty but the `AreaCode` value is, then you need an attribute that is applied only to the `PhoneNumber` property, and that attribute needs to accept a parameter for the other property name.

Model

```
public string AreaCode { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a phone number")]
[RequiredWith("AreaCode", ErrorMessage = "Please also enter an Area Code")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Validation attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class RequiredWithAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string _DefaultErrorMessage = "The {0} is also required.";
    private readonly string _OtherPropertyName;

    public RequiredWithAttribute(string otherPropertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(otherPropertyName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("otherPropertyName");
        }
        _OtherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
        ErrorMessage = _DefaultErrorMessage;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(_OtherPropertyName);
            var otherPropertyValue = otherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            if (otherPropertyValue == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format(ErrorMessageString, _OtherPropertyName));
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(_OtherPropertyName),
            ValidationType = "requiredwith",
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("dependentproperty", _OtherPropertyName);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

And add the following scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // General function to get the associated element
    myValidation = {
        getDependantProperyID: function (validationElement, dependantProperty) {
            if (document.getElementById(dependantProperty)) {
                return dependantProperty;
            }
            var name = validationElement.name;
            var index = name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
            dependantProperty = (name.substr(0, index) + dependantProperty).replace(/[\.\[\]]/g, "_");
            if (document.getElementById(dependantProperty)) {
                return dependantProperty;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    $.validator.addMethod("requiredwith", function (value, element, params) {
        var dependantControl = $('#' + params.dependentproperty);
        return dependantControl.val() !== '';
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("requiredwith", ["dependentproperty"], function (options) {
        var element = options.element;
        var dependentproperty = options.params.dependentproperty;
        dependentproperty = myValidation.getDependantProperyID(element, dependentproperty);
        options.rules['requiredwith'] = {
            dependentproperty: dependentproperty
        };
        options.messages['requiredwith'] = options.message;
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I m not wrong MultiFieldRequired is used above *class name* which was explain in below **stackoverflow** link earlier:
[MVC3 Validating Multiple Fields As A Single Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013172/mvc3-validating-multiple-fields-as-a-single-property)

You can also try below method in model.Also
*Add namespace in*

> model

=====================

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

=====================

```
 public class Customer
    {
        //...other fields here
         [Remote("ValidateAreaPhoneNumber","Home",AdditionalFields="PhoneNumber",ErrorMessage="Please enter a phone number")]

        public string AreaCode { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

You may write the method named

> ValidateAreaPhoneNumber

in ur

> Home Controller

as below:

```
public JsonResult ValidateAreaPhoneNumber(string PhoneNumber)
{

    //True:False--- action that implement to check PhoneNumber uniqueness

      return false;//Always return false to display error message
}
```