# How to validate multiField in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, validation, fluentvalidation, rule-engine

how to validate MultiFieldRequired  as one property to output one error message , and 
integrated with jquery client validation in mvc3 ?

i tried with [MultiFieldRequired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075339/mvc-form-validation-on-multiple-fields)   here , but there is no client validation message .

can [fluentvalidation.net](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) or [rulesengine](http://rulesengine.codeplex.com/) do this ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the client side, on the server side you can implement **IValidateableObject** and provide single message validation that way.

```
public IEnumerable Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(field2))
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult("Your single validation message");
    }
}
```

Comment: He did say "and integrated with jquery client validation in mvc3"

Comment: @Adam , then how can i get validationresult to put into modelstate

Comment: Thanks @MystereMan, I saw that. There's no other responses hence my post 'if you don't care' as they may actually not care as long as a validation result shows up to the client. Its an option, choose it or not, but you are more than welcome to post your own alternative.

Comment: @dfang MVC will automatically call the interface methods and put the ValidationResult into ModelState assuming you are allowing the model binder to do its magic. I believe UpdateModel/TryUpdateModel will do this as well off the top of my head.

Comment: @AdamTuliper i tried , it works , but how can i integrated with jquery client validation , can you give me some clue ?