# How to apply Custom Validation rules to ViewModel attribute in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, validation

In my MVC application I have the following `ViewModel`:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public int StartYear { get; set; }
   public int? StartMonth { get; set; }
   public int? StartDay { get; set; }

   public int? EndYear { get; set; }
   public int? EndMonth { get; set; }
   public int? EndDay { get; set; }

   [DateStart]
   public DateTime StartDate
   {
       get
       {
           return new DateTime(StartYear, StartMonth ?? 1, StartDay ?? 1);
       }
   }

   [DateEnd(DateStartProperty="StartDate")]
   public DateTime EndDate
   {
       get
       {
           return new DateTime(EndYear ?? DateTime.MaxValue.Year, EndMonth ?? 12, EndDay ?? 31);
       }
   }
 }
```

I do not use a calendar helper because I need the date in this format (there is a logic behind). Now I created my Custom Validation rule:

```
    public sealed class DateStartAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            DateTime dateStart = (DateTime)value;
            return (dateStart > DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    public sealed class DateEndAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string DateStartProperty { get; set; }
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            // Get Value of the DateStart property
            string dateStartString = HttpContext.Current.Request[DateStartProperty];
            DateTime dateEnd = (DateTime)value;
            DateTime dateStart = DateTime.Parse(dateStartString);

            // Meeting start time must be before the end time
            return dateStart < dateEnd;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `DateStartProperty` (in this case `StartDate`) is not in the `Request` object since it is calculated after the form is posted to the server. Therefore the `dateStartString` is always null. How can I get the value of `StartDate`?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use reflection to get the other property as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075339/mvc-form-validation-on-multiple-fields) (which seems a bit hacky to me), or create a custom validation attribute for the class rather than a single property as discussed [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1600450.aspx/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/multiplefields.

Hope this helps~

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a server-side validation.