# Valid values for ModelClientValidationRule ValidationType string?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

Is there a lsit of what validation rule types are directly available, without having to code a new one?

e.g.

JQuery.validation has "min(value)"

But I have tried

```
var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
rule.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage;
rule.ValidationParameters.Add("required", true);
rule.ValidationParameters.Add("min", _minDate);
rule.ValidationType = "min";
yield return rule;
```

without success.

Are the only options the inherited classes?

Answer (score 5):

Taken from [jquery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods), I would suspect you cannot use date type but convert your date to a number and it will probably work.

[image]

Comment: What number is required for Date?

Comment: var aDate = $("#date").val().split('-');
    var epoch = new Date(aDate[0] + "," + aDate[1] + "," + aDate[2]).getTime() / 1000;

Comment: Can't get it to work at all :(  Was hoping not to have to write my own validatiobn functions.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Remote Client Side Validation with FluentValidation](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/remote-client-side-validation-with-fluentvalidation), you can make use of the existing remote validator by doing

```
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ValidationType = "remote",
                ErrorMessage = message
            };
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("url", "/api/validation/uniqueemail");

            yield return rule;
```

I think you can change the type you want to use by specify the **ValidationType**.

You can get the [List of built-in Validation methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods).
Refer to that table, it includes the *required* and *min* you need.